# crystal reports asp.net moving out text

Tags: asp.net, html, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have winform application with crystal reports form. It rendering nice(see right picture below). Today, i tried create a WEB form with my report, and i receive moving out text(sell left picture below). Help me pleace.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/9rhmy.jpg this is picture

Comment: have u try with print because browser have different setting

Comment: print is nice, like in webform

Answer (score 0):

It seems that columns settings in Crystal report file has incorrect settings (width, text wrapping, etc) to make report look same in different "modes" you should specify this settings cause report viewer is different in WinForms and WebForms

Comment: how i can specify settings in web crystal report viewer?

Comment: Setting should be specified in Crystal Report file (*.rpt)